# Los comandos lspci y lsusb no me muestra nada en Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows

no se si alguno sabe porque estos dos comandos `sudo lspci` y `sudo lsusb` no me muestra los dispositivos que tengo conectados en el PCI y los dispositivos USB que tengo conectados. Cuando ejecuto esos comandos en la ultima versión de Ubuntu (version 22.0) que tengo instalado en Windows con SWL, no me aparece nada D:

Agradezco mucho cualquier ayuda

Answer (score 0):

esta es un version muy beta aun y no esta del todo integrada con windows
por lo que algunas comandos no funcionan del todo bien

si no viene por defecto debes hacer un:

```
sudo apt install pciutils
```

Comment: instale el paquete pero al ejecutar esos comandos me sigue sin mostrar nada de información